# Ignoring Unique Validation on Update Fucntion Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, updating

I have this `customer` model which when you create has a unqiue `phone_num` . It works fine in create but in my update function, which is a form with auto-populated values based from the `id`. If the user only updated the `address` as expected the `unique` validation will trigger again saying `The phone num has already been taken.` How can I handle this? I want the user to be able to update it's information ignoring the `unique` validation if the `phone_num` is still the same thus allowing the `unique` validation if the user chooses to change the `phone_num`

My code:

```
public function update($id)
{
    $rules = array(
        'title'             => 'required',
        'firstname'         => 'required',
        'lastname'          => 'required',
        'gender'            => 'required',
        'birthdate'         => 'required',
        'age_bracket'       => 'required',
        'addr1'             => 'required',
        'addr2'             => 'required',
        'addr3'             => 'required',
        'addr4'             => 'required',
        'town'              => 'required',
        'country'           => 'required',
        'postcode'          => 'required',
        'phone_num'         => 'required|unique:customers',
        'phone_type'        => 'required',
        'work_status'       => 'required',
        'home_status'       => 'required',
        'marital_status'    => 'required',

    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);


    // Check if all fields is filled
    if ($validator->fails()) 
    {
        return Redirect::to('customer/'.$id.'/edit')->withErrors($validator);
    }
    else
    {
        $customer = Customer::find($id);
        $customer->title           = Input::get('title');
        $customer->gender          = Input::get('gender');
        $customer->firstname       = Input::get('firstname');
        $customer->lastname        = Input::get('lastname');
        $customer->postcode        = Input::get('postcode');
        $customer->addr1           = Input::get('addr1');
        $customer->addr2           = Input::get('addr2');
        $customer->addr3           = Input::get('addr3');
        $customer->addr4           = Input::get('addr4');
        $customer->addr4           = Input::get('addr4');
        $customer->town            = Input::get('town');
        $customer->country         = Input::get('country');
        $customer->phone_num       = Input::get('phone_num');
        $customer->phone_type      = Input::get('phone_type');
        $customer->birthdate       = Input::get('birthdate');
        $customer->work_status     = Input::get('work_status');
        $customer->home_status     = Input::get('home_status');
        $customer->marital_status  = Input::get('marital_status');
        $customer->agebracket      = Input::get('age_bracket');

        if($customer->save())
        {
            Session::flash('alert-success', 'Form Submitted Successfully.');
        }
        else
        {
            Session::flash('alert-danger', 'Error on submitting form.');
        }

        return Redirect::to('customer/'.$id.'/edit');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `unique` rule takes some additional parameters for just this purpose which looks like `unique:table,column,except,idColumn`

So in your case, `except` would be the `id` and `idColumn` would be the name of the column of your id, probably `id`.

So with that in mind, you'd want your validation rule to be...

```
'required|unique:customers,phone_num,'.$id.',id'
```

Answer (score 5):

In L5.3+ you could handle it fluently using the Rule Facade. Note that the 
validation rules will now be arrays instead of using the | delimeter.
    use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

```
Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
    ],
 ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

or what you could do in your Form Request is (for Laravel 5.3+)

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [

            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$this->user, //here user is users/{user} from resource's route url
               ];
    }
```

i've done it in Laravel 5.6 and it worked.

Comment: I had problem in Laravel 8 how to define this option when I'm using update via API and fields are not same, and also not using ID as determined parameter for user.

If you are using slug, and URL parameter is not ID, maybe user/{slug} you can set up in Request file rule like this:

`Rule::unique('users', 'email')->ignore($this->route('manage_user'), 'slug')`

`Users` is table, `email` is column, `manage_user` is route parameter and `slug` is column that Rule will check.