# Laravel 9 and Livewire Validation for Unique Unless Updating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

The below validation works when creating a new record, but when updating a record, `partner_code` and `seedgens_code` are getting caught in the `unique` validation.  How do I allow a record to be updated with the same values if not changed, but still validate for unique when the value does change?

```
$this->validate(
    [
        'partner_code' => 'required|unique:varieties',
        'seedgens_code' => 'required|unique:varieties',
    ],
    [
        'partner_code.required' => 'Please add a partner code.',
        'partner_code.unique' => 'Partner code must be unique.',
        'seedgens_code.required' => 'Please add a unique partner code.',
        'seedgens_code.unique' => 'SeedGens code must be unique.',
    ],
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignoring Unique Validation on Update Fucntion Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340314/ignoring-unique-validation-on-update-fucntion-laravel-5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'partner_code' => 'required|unique:varieties,' . $id
```

or

```
'partner_code' => ['required', Rule::unique('varieties')->ignore($id)]
```

where `$id` is the ID that you want to ignore.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique

Comment: `'partner_code' => ['required', Rule::unique('varieties')->ignore($id)]` worked great!

Answer (score 0):

```
(1) protected $rules=[
    'partner_code' => ['required', Rule::unique('varieties')->ignore($id)]
    ....
]

(2) protected function rules(){
    'partner_code' => ['required', Rule::unique('varieties')->ignore($id)]
    ...
}
```

I add rule into (1) is not working
I add rule into (2) is working !!!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33048456)