# How can i Skip email Form unique Validation when update user data In Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

Hello Guys And Hi I Have This Validation Inside My Request

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:admins,email,' ,
        'name' => 'required|unique:admins,name',
        'code' => 'required|min:2|unique:admins,code',
        'password' => 'required|min:8',

        ];
    }
```

I want to ignore an email when updating data during the unique check. For example, consider an "update profile" screen that includes the user's name, e-mail address, I want to verify that the e-mail address is unique. However, if the user only changes the name field and not the e-mail field, I do not want a validation error to be thrown because the user is already the owner of the e-mail address. I only want to throw a validation error if the user provides an e-mail address that is already used by a different user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignoring Unique Validation on Update Fucntion Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340314/ignoring-unique-validation-on-update-fucntion-laravel-5)

Comment: No It Doesen't work

Comment: I suspect you've implemented it incorrectly as it will work. However, for the sake of argument please consult the [Laravel unique validation rule documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique), specifically the *Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID* subsection.

Comment: Can you Use My Code to show it for me because i didn't understand

Comment: Read the documentation and try figuring it out yourself. If you still get stuck update your question with your revised code and where you're stuck.

Comment: Undefined variable $id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247125/discussion-between-laravel-and-peppermintology).

Comment: @Peppermintology Where are you

Comment: Show the route please

Comment: I'm Fixing it Don't Thanks

Comment: The Error was Undefined variable $id  But I'm Passing it in my blade

Comment: i'm sorry to my sake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Fixing It I'm Passing The Id To The Request Like This

```
<input name='id' value="$item -> id" hidden >
```

and i write in Validation

```
  'email' => 'required|email|unique:admins,email,' . $this -> id ,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'email' = ['required', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user) ]
```

Laravel will automatically extract the id from the $user model or you can pass the id,

```
'email' = ['required',Rule::unique('users', 'email_address')->ignore($user->id) ]
```